# how to pass asp:textbox to javascript in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a java-script function `GetLocation(textbox)` which accepts a parameter and called on blur of asp text box in this way
 `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDestAddress" Style="text-transform: uppercase;" onblur="GetLocation(this);" CssClass="address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

I have to call GetLocation function from some where else where I am setting TextBoxDestAddress text property on listbox item selection after this I want to call GetLocation function and pass TextBoxDestAddress as parametere to GetLocation. In bellow code this keyword tells which textbox has text and it works fine

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDestAddress" Style="text-transform: uppercase;" onblur="GetLocation(this);" CssClass="address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

but when I fills textbox text from some where else how can I tell to the function that which text box has text in it.

need some sample code

thanks

Comment: Not cleared. can you further elaborate what exactly is required.

Comment: edited plz have a look

Comment: Sorry still not get your point what is required here. OnBlur even your function is working fine. Now do you need to call this same function from some other event, e.g. on a separate button click you want to call this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `blue` function.

Read the docs: https://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
$('#TextBoxDestAddress').blur();
```

Keep attention that in .Net this ID can be different than specified in the .aspx file.